# how to make bash prompt more readable in .bashrc - this is do with date but even overall

Tags: bash, debian, prompt

This is my .bashrc or at least the section containing the prompt -

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\A\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\d:\A\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Now as can be seen my prompt is -

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\d\A\$ '
```

Now while my immediate concern is if it's possible to have a space between the date and time

```
\d\A
```

as the prompt looks something like this -

```
shirish@think-debian:~Tue Oct 2001:03$
```

more problematic is the fact that the prompt is unreadable unless I know the syntax. Is y there a way to fix that ?

Comment: the **best answer** for clarity is [chepner's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237554/93777), the Glenn Jackman (author of the accepted answer agrees).  You should probably change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build up the value piecemeal, commenting along the way

```
PS1='\u@\h:'   # User@Host:
PS1+='\w'      # Working directory
PS1+='\d'      # date
PS1+=' '
PS1+='\A'      # Time
PS1+='\$ '     # Marker
```

Answer (score 3):

> Now while my immediate concern is if it's possible to have a space between the date and time

Yes. Put a space between the date and the time:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\d \A\$ '
```

> more problematic is the fact that the prompt is unreadable unless I know the syntax. Is y there a way to fix that ?

You can add arbitrary text to your prompt however you like:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w date:\d time:\A\$ '
```

Answer (score 3):

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w \d \A\$ '
```

going to extremes of readability:

```
declare -A prompt=(
    [user]='\u'
    [host]='\h'
    [dir]='\w'
    [date]='\d'
    [time]='\A'
    [prompt]='\$ '
)
PS1="${prompt[user]}@${prompt[host]}:${prompt[dir]} ${prompt[date]} ${prompt[time]} ${prompt[prompt]}"
```

Comment: chepner's answer is better than this.